# Cron job scheduling for last Saturday of every month at 09:00 AM

Tags: cron, schedule

Is their any way to schedule a CRON Job, which triggers the script only on last Saturday of the month.
Please advise.

Comment: perhaps using a series of at commands (12 of them, one for each month where you specify the actual date of the last Sat of every month) There is a spreadsheet formula for finding this https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-weekday-in-month - =(eomonth)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to schedule the job to run *every* Saturday, but make execution of the actual command conditional on the month one week hence, ex.

```
0 9 * * 6    [ "$(date +\%b -d 'next week')" = "$(date +\%b)" ] || somecommand
```

Note that the `%` character is special in crontabs, and needs to be escaped.